# Translating MIB to OID and a Juniper Switch

Tags: monitoring, snmp, juniper, oid, mib

2 chained EX 4500 I'd like to monitor using SNMP.

http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB17526

Can anyone please explain how did he translate "jnxOperatingDescr" to "1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1.5" ?

Thanks!

Comment: The [MIB file 'mib-jnx-chassis.txt'](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.1/topics/reference/mibs/mib-jnx-chassis.txt), referenced in your linked article, is used to perform the translation.  Are you asking how MIBs work?

Comment: How is that file used to perform the translation?
I mean using what command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,  IANA assigns OIDs under 1.3.6.1.4.1 which are "Private Enterprises." Juniper has 1.3.6.1.4.1.2636 (see http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.4.1.html).

To get the rest it is better to trace backwards from the last element "jnxOperatingDescr." Here is the definition:

```
jnxOperatingDescr OBJECT-TYPE
  SYNTAX        DisplayString (SIZE (0..255))
  MAX-ACCESS    read-only
  STATUS        current
  DESCRIPTION
    "The name or detailed description of this subject."
  ::= { jnxOperatingEntry 5 }
```

The last line indicates the last number in the OID is 5 and the parent is jnxOperatingEntry. Looking at the definition for jnxOperatingEntry and you'll find "::= { jnxOperatingTable 1 }" so the next entry is 1 and the parent is jnxOperatingTable. Tracing these all the way back you get 3.1.13.1.5. Concatentate Juniper's private enterprise 1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1.5.

Comment: isnt there a way to do this using snmptranslate or something?

Comment: Yes: "snmptranslate -On JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperatingDescr". You need to have the Juniper MIBs from http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/release-independent/junos/mibs/mibs.html

Comment: I get many "unlinked OID"...
what am I missing?

Comment: What I did: cd ~/.snmp/mibs; wget http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/junos/junos133/juniper-mibs-13.3R1.6.tgz; tar zxf juniper-mibs-13.3R1.6.tgz; mv JuniperMibs/* .; snmptranslate -On JUNIPER-MIB::jnxOperatingDescr (NET-SNMP version: 5.7.2.1)

Comment: I dont know why but it simply didnt work with the files inside the ZIP file I downloaded. The tar file worked flawlessly. Thanks alot!